# ps -ef output gives complete text

Tags: unix

```
$ ps -ef | grep -i 6919
epiphany  6919  6900   0 06:08:50 ?           2:40 /opt_local/crm/pacman/bea/jdk/bin/java -client -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xms2048m -
```

I need the complete text of this ps -ef. Given abolve is giving small text only

Answer (score 0):

Try

`ps -fww -p 6919`

The `-ww`  should treat the terminal as having unlimited columns.

The `-p` just gives you the desired process, saving you the pipe to `grep`.

If it's truncating due to window size, try redirecting the output to a file and looking there.